# Are global hotkeys in a C# Mono project possible on Linux?

Tags: c#, linux, mono

So I'm creating a screenshotting app for Linux/Windows using Mono and C#, and while there's extensive documentation on how to do global key combinations with Windows - there's next to none for Linux.

Is it actually possible to do global key listening in C# - do I have to write something in C, and if so, can you point me to a well documented bit of code for doing so (I have no C experience at all).

An example of this would be hitting 'Ctrl + Print Screen' when the application is not in focus, to prompt an application method.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider re-wording your question to match answer. You really should start with "does Linux support unified way for setting global hotkeys" and than see how to implement it in C#....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different Desktop Environment / Window Managers in Linux handle keyboard shortcuts differently.  Different distros can have varying configuration file locations.

You'll have to choose which targets you'll support, and work from there.